# Rounding error in Rust trying to create CORDIC table for sin function

Tags: rust, cordic

I am trying to implement the CORDIC method in `rust` using [this c implementation](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~jhw/cordic/) as an example, however i am having rounding error issues when generating the table. Here is my code and the results.

```
fn generate_table () {
    let pi: f32 = 3.1415926536897932384626;
    let k1: f32 = 0.6072529350088812561694; // 1/k
    let num_bits: uint = 32;
    let num_elms: uint = num_bits;
    let mul: f32 = 1073741824.000000; // 1<<(bits-2)

    println!("Cordic sin in rust");
    println!("num bits {}", num_bits);
    println!("mul {}", mul);
    println!("pi is {}", pi);
    println!("k1 is {}", k1);

    let shift: f32 = 2.0;
    for ii in range(0, num_bits) {
        let ipow: f32 = 1f32/shift.powi(ii as i32);
        let cur: f32 = ipow.atan() * mul;
        //println!("table values {:.10f}", cur);
        println!("table values 0x{}", std::f32::to_str_hex(cur));
    }
}

fn main() {
    generate_table();
}
```

which gives me the following table, notice the first and last values to see the biggest errors.

```
table values 0x3243f6c0
table values 0x1dac6700
table values 0xfadbb00
table values 0x7f56ea8
table values 0x3feab78
table values 0x1ffd55c
table values 0xfffaab
table values 0x7fff55.8
table values 0x3fffea.c
table values 0x1ffffd.6
table values 0xfffff.b
table values 0x7ffff.f8
table values 0x40000
table values 0x20000
table values 0x10000
table values 0x8000
table values 0x4000
table values 0x2000
table values 0x1000
table values 0x800
table values 0x400
table values 0x200
table values 0x100
table values 0x80
table values 0x40
table values 0x20
table values 0x10
table values 0x8
table values 0x4
table values 0x2
table values 0x1
table values 0x0.8
```

Why am i getting these (rounding?) errors and how do i fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer: How certain are you that you are feeding identical inputs into both computations?  In particular, the C implementation you quote says:

    `int mul = (1<<(bits-2));`

while you have hard-coded:

    `let mul: f32 = 1073741824.000000; // 1<<(bits-2)`

Note 1: You have changed the type of `mul` from an `int` to an `f32`.

Note 2: In the output I get when I run your program, I see this:

`mul 1073741844`

Notably, this is different from the hard-coded constant you wrote above; it is off by 20.

---

My usual way to debug a problem like this, and that I actually did in this case before I noticed the problem above, is to instrument both the C and the Rust versions of the code with printouts of the values of each intermediate expression, in order to identify where things start to differ and therefore narrow down which operation is introducing an "error."

In this case, it involved modifying the C code and the Rust code in parallel to print out a table of not just the `i` (or `ii` in the Rust version) and the output `c`, but also every intermediate result.

Here is the code for each of those, along with the output tables I got in the end.  (But then it was only analyzing those tables that I realized that the two `mul` values differed!)

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415926536897932384626
#define K1 0.6072529350088812561694

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int bits = 32; // number of bits
    int mul = (1<<(bits-2));


    int n = bits; // number of elements. 
    int c;

    printf("Cordic sin in C\n");
    printf("num bits %d\n", bits);
    printf("mul %d\n", mul);
    printf("pi is %g\n", PI);
    printf("k1 is %g\n", K1);

    float shift = 2.0;
    printf("computing c = atan(pow(2, -i)) * mul\n");
    printf("       i \t       c           p           a       c2\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        c = (atan(pow(2, -i)) * mul);
        int neg_i = -i;
        double p = pow(2, neg_i);
        double a = atan(p);
        int c2 = a * mul;;
        printf("% 8d \t 0x%08X % 12g % 12g 0x%08X\n", i, c, p, a, c2);
    }
}
```

Rust code:

```
fn generate_table () {
    let pi: f32 = 3.1415926536897932384626;
    let k1: f32 = 0.6072529350088812561694; // 1/k
    let num_bits: uint = 32;
    let num_elms: uint = num_bits;
    let mul: f32 = 1073741824.000000; // 1<<(bits-2)

    println!("Cordic sin in rust");
    println!("num bits {}", num_bits);
    println!("mul {}", mul);
    println!("1 << (bits - 2): {}", (1i << (num_bits-2)) as f32);
    println!("pi is {}", pi);
    println!("k1 is {}", k1);

    let shift: f32 = 2.0;
    println!("computing c = (1f32/shift.powi(ii as i32)).atan() * mul");
    println!("       i \t       c           p            a        c2\n");
    for ii in range(0, num_bits) {
        let ipow: f32 = 1f32/shift.powi(ii as i32);
        let cur: f32 = ipow.atan() * mul;
        let a = ipow.atan();
        let c2 = a * mul;
        //println!("table values {:.10f}", cur);
        // println!("table values 0x{}", std::f32::to_str_hex(cur));
        println!("{:8u} \t 0x{:8s} {:12f} {:12f} 0x{:8s}",
                 ii,
                 std::f32::to_str_hex(cur),
                 ipow,
                 a,
                 std::f32::to_str_hex(c2),
                 );
    }
}

fn main() {
    generate_table();
}
```

Tables generated:

```
% gcc gentable2.c && ./a.out
Cordic sin in C
num bits 32
mul 1073741824
pi is 3.14159
k1 is 0.607253
computing c = atan(pow(2, -i)) * mul
       i           c           p           a       c2
       0     0x3243F6A8            1     0.785398 0x3243F6A8
       1     0x1DAC6705          0.5     0.463648 0x1DAC6705
       2     0x0FADBAFC         0.25     0.244979 0x0FADBAFC
       3     0x07F56EA6        0.125     0.124355 0x07F56EA6
       4     0x03FEAB76       0.0625    0.0624188 0x03FEAB76
       5     0x01FFD55B      0.03125    0.0312398 0x01FFD55B
       6     0x00FFFAAA     0.015625    0.0156237 0x00FFFAAA
       7     0x007FFF55    0.0078125   0.00781234 0x007FFF55
       8     0x003FFFEA   0.00390625   0.00390623 0x003FFFEA
       9     0x001FFFFD   0.00195312   0.00195312 0x001FFFFD
      10     0x000FFFFF  0.000976562  0.000976562 0x000FFFFF
      11     0x0007FFFF  0.000488281  0.000488281 0x0007FFFF
      12     0x0003FFFF  0.000244141  0.000244141 0x0003FFFF
      13     0x0001FFFF   0.00012207   0.00012207 0x0001FFFF
      14     0x0000FFFF  6.10352e-05  6.10352e-05 0x0000FFFF
      15     0x00007FFF  3.05176e-05  3.05176e-05 0x00007FFF
      16     0x00003FFF  1.52588e-05  1.52588e-05 0x00003FFF
      17     0x00001FFF  7.62939e-06  7.62939e-06 0x00001FFF
      18     0x00000FFF   3.8147e-06   3.8147e-06 0x00000FFF
      19     0x000007FF  1.90735e-06  1.90735e-06 0x000007FF
      20     0x000003FF  9.53674e-07  9.53674e-07 0x000003FF
      21     0x000001FF  4.76837e-07  4.76837e-07 0x000001FF
      22     0x000000FF  2.38419e-07  2.38419e-07 0x000000FF
      23     0x0000007F  1.19209e-07  1.19209e-07 0x0000007F
      24     0x0000003F  5.96046e-08  5.96046e-08 0x0000003F
      25     0x0000001F  2.98023e-08  2.98023e-08 0x0000001F
      26     0x0000000F  1.49012e-08  1.49012e-08 0x0000000F
      27     0x00000008  7.45058e-09  7.45058e-09 0x00000008
      28     0x00000004  3.72529e-09  3.72529e-09 0x00000004
      29     0x00000002  1.86265e-09  1.86265e-09 0x00000002
      30     0x00000001  9.31323e-10  9.31323e-10 0x00000001
      31     0x00000000  4.65661e-10  4.65661e-10 0x00000000
% rustc gentable.rs && ./gentable 
gentable.rs:5:9: 5:17 warning: unused variable: `num_elms`, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
gentable.rs:5     let num_elms: uint = num_bits;
                      ^~~~~~~~
Cordic sin in rust
num bits 32
mul 1073741844
1 << (bits - 2): 1073741844
pi is 3.141593
k1 is 0.607253
computing c = (1f32/shift.powi(ii as i32)).atan() * mul
       i           c           p            a        c2

       0     0x3243f6c0            1     0.785398 0x3243f6c0
       1     0x1dac6700          0.5     0.463648 0x1dac6700
       2     0xfadbb00          0.25     0.244979 0xfadbb00 
       3     0x7f56ea8         0.125     0.124355 0x7f56ea8 
       4     0x3feab78        0.0625     0.062419 0x3feab78 
       5     0x1ffd55c       0.03125      0.03124 0x1ffd55c 
       6     0xfffaab       0.015625     0.015624 0xfffaab  
       7     0x7fff55.8     0.007813     0.007812 0x7fff55.8
       8     0x3fffea.c     0.003906     0.003906 0x3fffea.c
       9     0x1ffffd.6     0.001953     0.001953 0x1ffffd.6
      10     0xfffff.b      0.000977     0.000977 0xfffff.b 
      11     0x7ffff.f8     0.000488     0.000488 0x7ffff.f8
      12     0x40000        0.000244     0.000244 0x40000   
      13     0x20000        0.000122     0.000122 0x20000   
      14     0x10000        0.000061     0.000061 0x10000   
      15     0x8000         0.000031     0.000031 0x8000    
      16     0x4000         0.000015     0.000015 0x4000    
      17     0x2000         0.000008     0.000008 0x2000    
      18     0x1000         0.000004     0.000004 0x1000    
      19     0x800          0.000002     0.000002 0x800     
      20     0x400          0.000001     0.000001 0x400     
      21     0x200                 0            0 0x200     
      22     0x100                 0            0 0x100     
      23     0x80                  0            0 0x80      
      24     0x40                  0            0 0x40      
      25     0x20                  0            0 0x20      
      26     0x10                  0            0 0x10      
      27     0x8                   0            0 0x8       
      28     0x4                   0            0 0x4       
      29     0x2                   0            0 0x2       
      30     0x1                   0            0 0x1       
      31     0x0.8                 0            0 0x0.8     
%
```

Comment: Note also that the C code you were using as a model is calling `atan` and `pow`, which take `double` inputs (i.e., `f64` in Rust) ... for some reason you have switched to `f32` in your code (which would be like using `float` in C), which explains why the `1 << (bits - 2)` is not directly representable without loss of accuracy.  You should try switching to `f64` instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your very detailed answer. The 32 vs 64 bit thing has to be an it I think. I can tell by mul value (which i got from python) in rust i have http://is.gd/hZC0oy , which shows the two values. Switching to f64 definitely makes everything seem to go more smoothly. The 31st value of (what seems to be a hard 0 in c) vs rust's 0x0.8 might be display issue? I could also see how `powi()` which takes `f32` might cause additional rounding errors. I wonder if there is a reason why it maxes out at 32 bits?

Comment: @Victory: 0x0.8 is hex for 0.5. Is the result supposed to be 0.5 or 0?

Comment: @FrancisGagné - that is a very good question! I figured it is the `c` code as i was taking it as canonical, according to wolfram|alpha its .5  http://is.gd/zUvRE0